# Are there any other judgments of Solomon in Christian tradition?

Tags: solomon

Today I told the story of the Judgement of Solomon to my children, and they were so fascinated I proceeded to read them the Biblical text 1 Kings 3:16-28. They then asked me for 'more' of Solomon's judgments. I know that many wisdom writings are attributed to Solomon (Proverbs, The Wisdom of Solomon), but I have not been able to track down any other actual *judgements* of Solomon, ie cases brought before Solomon with his judgement. I might write a separate question on the Judaism stack exchange, but my question here is, **Are there any further judgements of Solomon to be found in the Christian tradition?** By "Christian tradition" I mean any text copied by Christian scribes (or otherwise published by Christians), even if the original source may have been Jewish or otherwise. I am not interested in canonicity or authenticity.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For what's on-topic here, see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question may or may not work on this site, since it's not really about Christianity as such. However, we'll see if anyone else has further thoughts on that.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean. Maybe I should dig around in Jewish literature some more then move my modified question to the Judaism Stack Exchange?